# MongoDB on Pi2 with ArchLinux does not work

Tags: mongodb, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2, archlinux-arm

Hey i always get an error when trying to start MongoDB on my RaspberryPi 2, which runs Arch Linux.
MongoDB is installed via pacman.

**Command:**

```
root@alarmpi ~ # mongo
```

**Error:**

```
2015-10-15T18:00:10.769+0000 F -        Invalid access at address: 0
2015-10-15T18:00:10.773+0000 F -        Got signal: 11 (Segmentation fault).

0x2f6120 0x2f57e0 0x2f5bf4 0x76320a30
----- BEGIN BACKTRACE -----
{"backtrace":[{"b":"10000","o":"2E6120"},{"b":"10000","o":"2E57E0"},
{"b":"10000","o":"2E5BF4"},{"b":"762F4000","o":"2CA30"}]}
mongo(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x2C) [0x2f6120]
mongo(+0x2E57E0) [0x2f57e0]
mongo(+0x2E5BF4) [0x2f5bf4]
libc.so.6(__default_rt_sa_restorer+0x0) [0x76320a30]
-----  END BACKTRACE  -----
```

Any suggestions how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem with mongoDB running on my cubieboard after upgrading. There seems to be a problem with the recent versions of MongoDB, at least on systems with arm architecture.

The segmentation fault occured on my system both with `mongodb-3.0.6-2-armv7h` and `mongodb-3.0.7-1-armv7h`. After downgrading to `mongodb-3.0.4-1-armv7h` the error was gone.

Have a look at `/var/cache/pacman/pkg`. Maybe you'll find an older version that works. This can be installed with:

```
pacman -U /var/cache/pacman/pkg/mongodb-3.0.4-1-armv7h.pkg.tar.xz
```

You can get more information on downgrading packages on the [Arch Linux WIKI](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Downgrading_packages).

Comment: Thanks for the hint, looks like the oldest version in `/var/cache/pacman/pkg` is  `mongodb-3.0.6-2-armv7h` any suggestions how i acquire version 3.0.4 ?

Comment: I've dropped it on a public server. You can get it at http://www.file-upload.net/download-10982512/mongodb-3.0.4-1-armv7h.pkg.tar.xz.html.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my raspberry pi B+.
My architecture was armv6h and didn't found the packages until now.
For lucky, some cool guy shared his own packages on the end of [this page](http://archlinuxarm.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=9374).
Thanks!

Comment: You are awesome!! As my Pi2 already works with MonogoDB now, thanks to @phlogratos, i was going to try out my raspberry pi but could not find any packages, now, thanks to you i am able to get it working! :)